# AJAX MVC3 jquery ajax call back always enters on success

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

im having the following issue i have this post action that is called by ajax:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AX_Login(LoginVM usersubmitted)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return Json(new { success = true });
   }
   else
   {
      return Json(new { success=false, error = true });
   }
}
```

For other hand i have the following jquery handler for a button:

```
    $("#Jquery_LoginButton").click(
        function () {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("AX_Login","Users"))",
            data:$("#MiniLoginForm").serialize(),
            success: function (result) 
            {
                alert("Good");
            },
            error: function () 
            {
                alert("Bad");
            }
        });

         }
    )
```

My Issue: The action is reached, but always the ajax call ends on sucess - even if the model is not valid -.

Questions:

- Do you know why this is happening if im setting to false the success? i could throw an exception if the model is not valid but i dont see the thing elegant.
- How do you manage normally the validation with Data Annotations and Ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is right that you always get "success" because your request
always work. `$.ajax` doesnt know what data comes back. 
So you will get `error` only if your request failes (404 for example)

you have to do this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@(Url.Action("AX_Login","Users"))",
    data:$("#MiniLoginForm").serialize(),
    success: function (result) 
    {
        if (result.success) 
        {
            alert("Good");
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("Bad");
        }
    },
    error: function () 
    {
        alert("Request failed");
    }
});
```

**hope this helps**

Comment: Done... Just one last question, do you have any url that explains whats the best way to now highlight the textboxes whose values are not valid? I could return from my json action the error messages, but is this the right way? Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: You can do this, but i dont know what you want exactly. You should read about validation. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/overview/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript